# Pandas: Cumulative count from two columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
winner  loser   winner_matches  loser_matches
Dave    Harry   1               1
Jim     Dave    1               2
Dave    Steve   3               1
```

I'm trying to build a running count of how many matches a player has participated in based on their name's appearance in either the winner or loser column (ie, `Dave` above has a running count of `3` since he's been in every match). I'm new to pandas and have tried a few combinations of `cumcount` and `groupby` but I'm not sure if I just need to manually loop over the dataset and store all the names myself.

EDIT: to clarify, I need the running totals in the dataframe as shown above and not just a Series printed out later on! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `MultiIndex Series` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), for `DataFrame` add [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
print (df)
  winner  loser
0   Dave  Harry
1    Jim   Dave
2   Dave  Steve

s = df.stack()
#if multiple columns in original df
#s = df[['winner','loser']].stack()
df1 = s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).unstack().add_suffix('_matches')
print (df1)
   winner_matches  loser_matches
0               1              1
1               1              2
2               3              1
```

Last append to original `DataFrame` by [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
  winner  loser  winner_matches  loser_matches
0   Dave  Harry               1              1
1    Jim   Dave               1              2
2   Dave  Steve               3              1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and works perfectly. I need to read up a bit on stacking it seems. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

you need [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html),

```
 pd.Series(df[['winner','loser']].values.flatten()).value_counts()
 [out]
 Dave     3
 Jim      1
 Harry    1
 Steve    1
```

Comment: This is cool but I need the running count to be available in the row, rather than being a different Series